# Using Room persistence library, can I set my own primary key and manage it's "uniqueness" on my own?

Tags: kotlin, primary-key, android-room

I am using the Room library. One of my entities is coded like this:

```
@Entity
data class Authentication (
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "system_id")
    val systemID: String = "demo",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "password")
    val password: String? = "demo",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "server_address")
    val serverAddress: String? = "https://www.someSite.com/login/"
)
```

make the `systemID` the primary key. This is my `Dao`:

```
@Dao
interface AuthDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAuth(auth: Authentication): Long 

    @Query("SELECT * FROM authentication WHERE system_id = 1")
    suspend fun getAuth(): Authentication?

    @Update
    suspend fun updateAuth(auth: Authentication): Int

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteAuth(auth: Authentication)
}
```

I am managing the systemId's on the server. I know they will all be unique. However when I try to insert an object my code throws and exception stating that my primary key failed it's unique constraint. When I insert `onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE` (as seen in the code above) everything works fine but before I placed that there my app crashed.

I checked the docs and didn't really find the answer to my question. I want to know why this error is thrown even when I KNOW I haven't tried to insert another object with the same systemID. Does Room not trust me? Is it because I didn't allow Room to autogenerate the primary key and thus Room and the compiler can't trust that I won't duplicate primary keys? Or am I missing something else?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Perhaps I should have added this to my question. This is the code that has me confused.

```
fun checkForAuthenticationInDatabase() {
        launch(IO){
            var auth = AuthDatabase(getApplication()).authDao().getAuth()
            if (auth == null){
                Log.d("TAG", "auth was null")
                auth = Authentication()
                AuthDatabase(getApplication()).authDao().insertAuth(auth)
                Log.d("TAG", auth.toString())
            }
            withContext(Main){
                authentication.value = auth
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I first check for the existence of an object. If it doesn't exist and it comes back null, then I insert one. If it does exist, I just grab it. What I didn't catch before posting this question is that originally I was using int for the primary key (starting with 1 and no autogenerate). *There is supposed to be only one row(record) in this database.* Then I changed it to use the systemID as a primary key instead of an int but I forgot to change the query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM authentication WHERE system_id = 1")
    suspend fun getAuth(): Authentication?
```

I realized my mistake and wanted to post this for others that may make the same mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even when I KNOW I haven't tried to insert another object with the same systemID

From your description of the error and that using REPLACE fixes the issue, then there is a row in the database that is the same system_id that you are trying to insert.

Notice that the description given is a little different to yours. SQLite, for which Room is basically a wrapper has no concept of storing objects, but of storing data in rows, each row containing the same number of elements (albeit that some may be null).

The difference between objects in an App and even if you equate a row in the database to an object (which it may represent and will in Room), is that in the database the data is persisted and remains in the database when the App is restarted. Perhaps it is this persistence that is confusing you.

If you change/use

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM authentication WHERE system_id = :system_id")
suspend fun getAuth(system_id: String): Authentication?
```

- having `@Query("SELECT * FROM authentication WHERE system_id = 1")
  suspend fun getAuth(): Authentication?` is prettymuch useless as it only allows you to extract 1 Authentication from the database, one which probably doesn't exist.

And use this prior to inserting, using the system_id, that you are inserting this will very likely confrim the case. That is that it will find the data and return a valid (non null) Authentication object .

> Does Room not trust me? 
>   To some extent yes, to some extent no.
>
> Is it because I didn't allow Room to autogenerate the primary key and thus Room and the compiler can't trust that I won't duplicate primary keys?

No. Your code works fine and allows uniqueness when given.

> Or am I missing something else?
>   As explained above, I believe that this is the case. Again with unique values for system_id the code works fine (this does assume that there are no other entities).

Consider the following which bar -

- adding `@Query("SELECT * FROM authentication")
  fun getAllAuth(): List<Authentication>` to AuthDao
- removing **suspend** to allow running from the main thread (for convenience)

uses your code :-

```
    val authDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(this,AuthDatabase::class.java,"authdb")
        .allowMainThreadQueries()
        .build()
    var a1 = Authentication("system_id1","password","www.server.etc")
    var a2 = Authentication("system_id2","password","xxx.server.etc")
    Log.d("AUTHINSERT","Insert of Authentication returned " + authDatabase.authDao().insertAuth(a1))
    Log.d("AUTHINSERT","Insert of Authentication returned " + authDatabase.authDao().insertAuth(a2))
    Log.d("AUTHINSERT","Insert of Authentication returned " + authDatabase.authDao().insertAuth(a1))
    var authentications = authDatabase.authDao().getAllAuth()
    for (authentication in authentications) {
        Log.d("AUTHINFO",authentication.systemID)
    }
```

Running this for the first time results in the log containing :-

```
2020-01-09 16:39:58.351 D/AUTHINSERT: Insert of Authentication returned 1
2020-01-09 16:39:58.352 D/AUTHINSERT: Insert of Authentication returned 2
2020-01-09 16:39:58.354 D/AUTHINSERT: Insert of Authentication returned 3
2020-01-09 16:39:58.358 D/AUTHINFO: system_id2
2020-01-09 16:39:58.358 D/AUTHINFO: system_id1
```

That is three rows appear to have been inserted, with rowid's 1-3.

- rowid is a normally hidden row that has a unique integer (64bit signed) provided by SQLite sqlite (unless the rowid is aliased).

However, only 2 Authentication objects have been output. This is because the row with a rowid of 1 has been deleted and the row with a rowid of 3 has been added. That's what REPLACE does.

If the code above is run again then the result is :-

```
2020-01-09 16:44:25.455 D/AUTHINSERT: Insert of Authentication returned 4
2020-01-09 16:44:25.456 D/AUTHINSERT: Insert of Authentication returned 5
2020-01-09 16:44:25.458 D/AUTHINSERT: Insert of Authentication returned 6
2020-01-09 16:44:25.462 D/AUTHINFO: system_id2
2020-01-09 16:44:25.462 D/AUTHINFO: system_id1
```

That is the data in the database has been retained and because the data in the objects (albeit that they are not the same objects as the objects would have been garbage collected and deleted) is the same. The two rows have been deleted and new rows inserted (rowid's 5 and 6 will be in the database).

Comment: Thank you MikeT. After reading your response I realized my mistake. Feel free to look at my edit to see. I should have added one more block of code to my original question. Any way, cheers. Credit given